# PHP 5.6 htmlentities with default charset

Tags: php, html-entities

We are on PHP 5.6.5, we migrated from 5.3. I have an issue with `htmlentities` that doesn't take the default charset that is set.

Since I have to set it because now the `default_charset` is "UTF-8", I have this issue:

```
ini_set("default_charset", "ISO-8859-1");
$foo = "in french: sécurité"; //that is in UTF-8

//this is not the same...
$new_foo1 = htmlentities( $foo );
//return empty string

//...as this
$new_foo2 = htmlentities( $foo, ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, 'ISO-8859-1');
//return it correctly
```

the doc clearly says:

```
string htmlentities ( string $string [, int $flags = ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401 [, string $encoding = ini_get("default_charset")
```

Its supposed the get the default charset set.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I set the default_charset in my PHP.INI file and it fixed the problem